# Why does my image stacking code cause color banding and overflow in the result?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I made a simple program to stack images with opencv. What it does is simply take two same pixels in two images and average the colours. Code works great except for brighter areas in the image.
Before using the program with different images I tested it with one image. Result should be the same as I use the same image. But after saving the image the darker areas of the image have not changed. But brighter areas have changed to different coloures.

This is the original image.

[image: original]

Image after stacking.

[image: stacked image]

This is the code I used. Written in python.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

np.seterr(over ="ignore") # hide numpy errors

# image folder
folder = "sample/"

# list all the images in folder
img_lst = [folder + i for i in os.listdir(folder)] 

# get number of row and columns in an image
img = cv2.imread(img_lst[0] , -1) 
print("processing image 1: " + img_lst[0], ", rows: " + str(img.shape[0]) + ", columns: " + str(img.shape[1]))

rows = img.shape[0]
columns = img.shape[1]

# output image
final_img = np.asarray(img)
final_img.setflags(write=True)

# stacking
img_num = 1; row = 0; column = 0; color = 0

while img_num< len(img_lst): # read all the images int he list

    img = np.asarray(cv2.imread(img_lst[img_num] , -1))
    print("processing image " + str(img_num + 1))
    
    # read all the pixels 
    while row< rows:
        while column< columns:
            while color<3:
                # average the color of image
                final_img[row][column][color] = int((final_img[row][column][color] + img[row][column][color])/2)
                color += 1
            
            color =0
            column += 1
        
        column = 0
        row += 1

    row = 0
    img_num += 1


print("finished...")              
cv2.imwrite(folder + "final.jpg", final_img) # write the final image
```

So what could be the problem. I thought this is because of RGB to BGR conversion in opencv. But seems like it's not.

Comment: It is not OpenCV, it is your processing, it seems you are overflowing pixel values. Read this: https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html

Comment: Oh.. I see what I got wrong now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Side note: `while row...: while column...:` (or `for row...: for column...`) is a strong antipattern with opencv (or any python image library). You should try and avoid iterating pixels yourself at all cost. And most of the time, it is avoidable. In your case, the whole `while row/while column/while color` loop could be replaced by `final_img = (final_img + img)/2` (it even reproduces the same overflow problem you have :D)

Comment: So, without the overflow, `final_img = ((final_img.astype(np.int16)+img.astype(np.int16))//2).astype(np.uint8)` should work

Comment: Also note (but maybe that is wanted) that the last `img` have as much weight in the final result, than all the others combined. If you have 4 images img₀, img₁, img₂, img₃, what you are doing is final=img₀, then final=(final+img₁)/2 ⇒ final=img₀/2+img₁/2. Then final=(final+img₂)/2 ⇒ final=img₀/4+img₁/4+img₂/2. Then final=(final+img₃)/2 ⇒ final=img₀/8+img₁/8+img₂/4+img₃/2

Comment: If your goal is just to stack all images and do the global average, I would just start from a 0 image, with a data type sufficient to hold the sum (`final=np.zeros((rows,columns,3), dtype=np.uint16)`). Then just add all images to it: `for name in img_list: final += cv2.imread(name)`. And then divide by the number of images, and convert to 8 bits the result `cv2.imwrite("final.jpg", (final/len(img_list)).astype(np.uint8))`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. pretty new to opencv.